# Backbone.js view variables being overwritten

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am creating views via a $.each and the myId attribute of all the views always ends up being overwritten by the myId of the last element.

Creation of views

```
 $('.form').each(function() {
        // split class name
        var classNameArray = $(this).attr('class').split('-');
        // get typeId from last part of classname
        var myId = classNameArray[classNameArray.length-1];
        new myView({ 'el': $('.form-' + myId), 'myId': myId });      
    });
```

Initialization of my view

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
events: {

},
initialize: function() {
    var myId = this.options.myId;

},
test: function() {
    console.log(myId); // will return myId of last view created
}

});
```

How can I get the views to keep their unique myId's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test: function() {
  console.log(myId); // will return myId of last view created
}
```

this [myId] is not the [myId] in :

```
initialize: function() {
    var myId = this.options.myId;    
}
```

it is the [myId] from :

```
$('.form').each(function() {
        // split class name
        var classNameArray = $(this).attr('class').split('-');
        // get typeId from last part of classname
        var myId = classNameArray[classNameArray.length-1]; //from this myId!!!
        new myView({ 'el': $('.form-' + myId), 'myId': myId });      
 });
```

**because:**

first:

```
"var myId = this.options.myId; "
```

this [myId] is the initialize within the local variables，you can not access this variable outside the method.

second:

```
console.log(myId); // will return myId of last view created
```

why are we here be able to access to [myId]?because this [myId] is the [this.myId],[this] is the context of the calling method :

```
new myView({ 'el': $('.form-' + myId), 'myId': myId });
```

so,this [myId] is the :

```
var myId = classNameArray[classNameArray.length-1];
```

[myId] here.this [myId] is cyclic change, so you always get the last cycle the value of the [myId].

**solution：**

```
initialize: function() {
    this.myId = this.options.myId;
},
```

because [this.myId] is [myView]'s internal variables, each time you create the instance of [myView], in the [initialize] method dynamically the [this.myId] is set to the correct value form [this.options.myId].

**kind of problem, you can refer to this article：**

http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-4-scope-chain

Answer (score 2):

When you write it like this --

```
initialize: function() {
    var myId = this.options.myId;
},
```

It creates a variable local to the *initialize* function (that's a Javascript thing, not a Backbone thing).

Try this instead (create a variable local to the *View* object):

```
initialize: function() {
    this.myId = this.options.myId;
},
```